# Relative adverbs

Tags: adverbs, relative-clauses

I am having some trouble understanding why relative adverbs function as adverbs in a relative clause.

My family worships in a church, where my parents married.

In the above example, I understand "where my parents married functions as an adjective clause, but cannot comprehend how where modifies the verb married.

Comment: Could you be more specific about why you don't understand this? It modifies *married* as an adverb, there isn't really a "why" about it. *Where* functions just like *there*; both refer back to *a church* and modify the verb of the second clause, but *there* is demonstrative and part of a main clause, whereas *where* introduces a subordinate clause. Just like *when/then* and *after which / afterwards* (in a way). There are relative pronouns, adjectives, and adverbs.

Answer (score 4):

A *relative* form is a pointer to some other constituent in a sentence. When a relative is employed, as here, in a bound relative clause, it points in two directions, toward an explicit constituent in the head clause and toward a missing constituent in the subordinate relative clause, and signifies that they are the same entity.

```
  This is [the dragon] which George killed [_].  
              ↑        ↵↳                  ↑
```

In other words, "This is the dragon. George killed the dragon. The two dragons are the same dragon."

*Where* is a 'pro-locative': it points to a locative expression in the same way that *who*, a pro-noun, points to a noun phrase. Since most locative expressions are preposition phrases (PP), *where* may usually be understood as a 'pro-PP', equivalent to *PREP which*. As a relative it points to an explicit placename in the head clause and to a missing preposition phrase in the relative clause. The only tricky part is figuring out which preposition is intended.

```
 My family worships in [a church] where my parents married [_].
                          ↑        ↵↳                      ↑
```

In other words, "My family worships in a church. My parents married **in a church**. The two churches are the same church."

Comment: Isn't *where* the pro-prep for *there* /relative version of *here/there*? :)

Comment: @Araucaria Sure, and you can make the same case for *who* always acting as a pro-noun for *he/him/she/her/they/them*. But introducing these  intermediate pro-forms strikes me as Ockhamly unshaven.

Comment: There's a method in the madness! As you say, *where* seems to be a Prep, but generally replaces what might be understood as a PP. Unlike *who* that can replace any kind of person, *where* is severely limited in the types of locative meanings it can have. For example, *where* cannot mean *above which*.  Now the only two preps that I know that work in this kind of way are *there* and *here* ...

Comment: Off the top of my head without thinking about it all that much, that is ... :)

Comment: @Araucaria and StoneyB:  Er, the OP's example has a comma in it; is that comma doable in there like that for the OP's example? And if it is doable, does it being a supplementary "where" relative word affect the analysis? That is, is the current analysis in this answer post written for integrated relatives only or is it valid for both integrated and supplementary relative clauses?

Comment: @F.E. I don't know. Does it? I'm in Devon without any refs. :)

Comment: @F.E. Hence you may have seen me using terms like "it-clefts" today ...

Comment: @Araucaria As to the first question of mine, it seems that the relative clause is being used to restrict or distinguish the talked about church from other churches, and so, I had assumed that it probably ought (or has to be?) integrated into the main clause. What do you think? :)

Comment: @F.E. I tend to agree, but am not absolutely sure about it. For example, "*My family worships in a really old synagogue*" "*Nice. My family worships in a church, where my parents got married in fact*" might kinda be ok?

Comment: @Araucaria Your example seems felicitous. But if you remove "in fact" from it, it seems to become infelicitous, maybe? What do you think? (aside: I doubt I can even pronounce that word "felicitous", especially not this early in the day.)

Comment: @F.E. In writing, yeas, it's not very good without the *in fact*. But might be ok with the right intonation in speech perhaps. Maybe it needs a little edit from a tiger?

Comment: @F.E. ( ... btw, all relative clauses are integrated. But, sshh, don't tell anyone :) )

Comment: @Araucaria Removing the comma from the OP's example might then help make the answer posts become (more) relevant, but is that the OP's actual intent--to discuss integrated relative clause--or did the OP actually mean to use a supplementary relative example?

Comment: @F.E. I doubt it, but you could ask him. I'm off to sit by the beach in the sunshine and drink some real Devon scrumpy. :)

Comment: @F.E. No, not sad, Great!!!!! I do really, really think though, that it would be great for readers there if you felt inclined to do a kindova simplified answer (writing-wise) :-) might be an interesting exercise.... :-) [like ten lines or so?]

Comment: @F.E. Could you give an undelete vote to the bottom answer in [this question here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/60065/how-do-you-say-100-000-000-000-000-000-000-in-words/60117#60117)  by any chance?

Comment: @Araucaria Sorry I missed you guys - I never got pinged on this conversation after my last post. {*grump* - 'sorry' specifically because you're my two favorite heretics and you make me think} 1.I agree that *where* has very limited range as far as positional reference goes; but it can get around this to some extent by taking a full locative rather than only a nominal as its antecedent. 2.I don't think restrictive/nonrestrictive makes any difference to how it works. But then I don't think there's any difference between fused relative clauses and embedded questions, either. ..

Comment: ... which is one of *my* main heresies. 3) While I'm at it, I might mention that *when* works pretty much the same way, and I classify that as prolocative, too. Every time I stop and think about what I've taken to calling locatives the subject gets weirder and weirder and makes my brain hurt.

Comment: @F.E. See previous two posts.

Answer (score 1):

"Where, when, why" can be used in relative clauses as in "the church where my parents married". In this use they are often called relative adverbs,  but the Longman English Grammar uses no name at all. The term adverb is perhaps not optimal. Here it does not mean that "where/when/why" modify a verb as an adverb of manner. The primary function is to connect the relative clause to the noun before. Perhaps we should or you should invent another term, if you have problems with adverb. You might say "relative connector", to make the function of the three words clearer. We have to live with the fact that not every traditional grammar term is optimal.

"The church where my parents married" is the same as "the church in which my parents married".

Comment: They're called adverbs because they mean time, place, and purpose, and so do many adverbs. Not a very good reason, and not a very good term. And note that they're not all the same -- _why_ can't be used to introduce a relative clause unless it modifies the word _reason_, but _where_ can be used with any place reference, and _when_ with any time reference -- or with any point in a story being told in linear installments.  What they are is relative pronouns, and a frequent use is to introduce headless relative clauses (or embedded question complements -- same thing): _where_ = _the place where_.

Answer (score 0):

Adjectival clauses are sometimes introduced by what are called the relative adverbs: where, when and why. Although the entire clause is adjectival and will modify a noun, the relative word itself fulfils an adverbial function (modifying a verb within its own clause).

The relative adverb where will begin a clause that modifies a noun of place:

*My family worships in a church **where** my parents married.*

The relative pronoun "where" modifies the verb "married" (which makes it adverbial), but the entire clause ("where my parents married") modifies the word "church."

This was the most convincing explanation I could find. After reading a couple of articles on this topic, I think that relative adverbs modify the verb in the clause they introduce because that is the way they work(just like adjectives modify nouns or adverbs modify adjectives, verbs and other adverbs)

Source: [Relative adverbs](http://www.english-for-students.com/Relative-Adverbs.html)